# how to calculate length of an IP address using php

Tags: php

How to calculate length of IP address ?

Comment: `$ip = '123.123.123.1';` You must look ip adress as string

Comment: What does `length of IP` mean?

Comment: OP, please do some elementary PHP tutorials first

Comment: Quote your IP address.

Comment: `$ip = '123.123.123.1';` it's a string, not some magical special data type

Comment: $ip = "123.123.123.1";
echo strlen($ip);

Comment: [This](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/computers-software/programming/php.html) will do the trick.

Comment: getAddresses_www() is not a native PHP function; but if it's [this](http://pastebin.com/nJFBSpGR) then it's returning an array of addresses, which are all strings

Comment: Yes **getAddresses_www** is is not a native PHP function. i have checked my code.

Comment: I updated my question. I can not touch to **$ip = 123.123.123.1; //do not touch this line** code. I added a box where you can convert this $ip and echo. but how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you want to get the length of the IP address string.
Your `$ip` variable is not a string at the moment.

Change to : `$ip = '123.123.123.1';` or `$ip = "123.123.123.1";`

`echo strlen($ip);` should work now.

**UPDATE:** (After reading your comment)

`getAddresses_www()` should be returning a string. There's no data type which has data in the format 123.123.123.1 unless you have it as a string.

**UPDATE 2:**

From your comment:

```
<?php 
function getAddresses_www() { 
    return 123.123.123.1; // This will give syntax error!!
                          // This should be returned as a string. 
                          // There's no such data type to return an ip like this.
} 

$ip = getAddresses_www(); //do not touch this line 

//you can write in this box ######### 
//you can apply your logics and functions just below. 
//############ box end 

echo strlen($ip); 
?>
```

**According to your question of whether 123.123.123.1 will work directly, the answer is NO, it will not work. It will give you a syntax error.**

Comment: The `// do not touch this line` is the line you should be touching. That has to be a string to make `strlen()` work. Please show the implementation or link to `getAddresses_www()` method.

Comment: do not focus on getAddresses_www() function. it just printing IP of website. and its' custom function.

Comment: What is it's return type? That's where the ip is coming from right (something like `$ip = getAddresses_www();`)?
What exactly is it returning?

Comment: it's returning **123.123.123.1** only

Comment: <?php
function getAddresses_www()
{
return 123.123.123.1;
}

$ip = getAddresses_www(); //do not touch this line
//you can write in this box #########
//you can apply your logics and functions just below.

//############ box end
echo strlen($ip);
?>

Comment: i added **'** before and last. it is **echo strlen('123.123.123.1');**

Comment: Sorry, I meant 123.123.123.1 directly in strlen()

Comment: See update above, especially the comment lines at the `return 123.123.123.1;` line.

Comment: No problem... All the best :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ip = "123.123.123.1";
echo strlen($ip);
```